# How to get the optional values from a map as an optional list?

Tags: list, dictionary, java-8, option-type, collectors

```
Map<Long, Optional<Long>> aMap = new HashMap<>();
```

This map has some keys and optional values.

```
Optional<List<Long>> valuesList = input.aMap().values().stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above way has compilation error. How do i get the optional list correctly?

Comment: The list returned by the collector is always not null. Why do you want to wrap it with `Optional`?

Comment: I think data type of the "valuesList" should be List<Optional<Long>> instead of Optional<List<Long>>.

Comment: what do you need to get from the map???

Comment: The ordinary Collection API is simpler in this case: `List<Optional<Long>> valuesList = new ArrayList<>(input.aMap().values());`

Comment: @Ganga I don't understand if you need to fix the compilation error by changing `Optional<List<Long>>` to `List<Optional<Long>>`, or if you actually need to get a `Optional<List<Long>>` from your map. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missundertand the return value, dont forget that a `Optional<List<Long>>` is an optional object that can have 1 list if present....

you need instead a `List<Optional<Long>>`

```
List<Optional<Long>> valuesList = input.aMap()
                   .values()
                   .stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to `stream` here, just to collect them to a `List`:

```
 List<Optional<Long>> list = new ArrayList<>(input.aMap().values());
```

Comment: The above method allows to get both List<Long> or List<Optional<Long>> whereas using Streams strictly allows me to get only List<Optional<Long>>. Not sure if that makes any difference, or in general if there is a difference between using streams and not for such operation.

Comment: @Ganga *The above method allows to get both List<Long> or List<Optional<Long>> whereas using Streams strictly allows me to get only List<Optional<Long>>* could you clarify this? You mean it would allow you to get the values that are present by applying a `filter`?

Comment: Nope i did not apply any filter, if you noticed 

ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa's answer, doing that strictly returns only a `List<Optional<Long>>` never a `List<Long> ` as this case allows. So i'm able to do even `List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>(input.aMap.values());`

Comment: @Ganga but `input.aMap.values()` returns a `Collection<Optional<Long>>` how is `List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>(input.aMap.values());` supposed to work?